# Get Place ID by Lat Long in Google Map in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to get `Google Place ID` from lat long or address? I have fetched location address by lat long, but no luck with `Place ID`. Can anyone please help me?
**My requirement is simple. I have lat long. fetched the address using lat long. Now I just need the place id of that address.**

Here is my Code:

```
let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { (response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            if let places = response?.results(){
                if let place = places.first{
                    print("GMS Address Place-->", place)
                    if let lines = place.lines{
                        print("GEOCODE: Formatted Address: \(lines[0])")
                        }
                }else{
                    print("GEOCODE: nil first in places")
                }
            }else{
                print("GEOCODE: nil in places")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out? I'm running into the same issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can with API nearbysearch URL: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
Hope help you!

Comment: i don't need multiple places. i need exact place for given lat long. but your given api provides multiple places with different lat long that doesn't match my given lat long.

Answer (score -1):

To get the place information like place id use [google Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-details).

Comment: the problem is i don't have any place id. I want to get placeid from lat long. And i think this is not available in places api for ios.